# Assigning specific values to a boolean array

Tags: julia, probability

Say I am tossing a fair coin where 'tails' is assigned the value x = -1/2 and 'heads' is assigned x = 1/2.

I do this N times and I want to obtain the sum. This is what I have tried:

```
p = 0.5
N = 1e4

X(N,p)=(rand(N).<p)
```

I know this is incomplete but when I check `(rand(N).<p)` I see an array consisting of `true, false`. I interpret this as 'Tails' or 'Heads'. However, I don't know how to assign the values 1/2 and -1/2 to each of these elements in order for me to find the sum. If I simply use `sum((rand(N).<p))` I do get an integer value, but I don't think this is the right way to do it because I haven't specified the values 1/2 and -1/2 anywhere.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the statement: `N = 10000 ; p = 0.5 ; v_head, v_tails = -0.5, 0.5 ; sum(x->ifelse(x, v_head, v_tails), rand(N).<p)` helpful to finding a solution?

Comment: and if you do not care about performance and want something simple consider `rand([-0.5, 0.5], 10000)`.

Comment: Thank you both for the reply. Since I am very new to programming @ Bogumił Kamiński's solution makes more sense to me because I can actually see the array it produces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by the comments already, you want to do

`sum(rand([-0.5, 0.5], N))`

where `N` must be an integer (you wrote `N=1e4`, therefore `typeof(N) == Float64` and `rand` won't work).

The documentation of `rand` (obtained by `?rand`) describes what `rand(S, N)` does:

> Pick a random element or array of random elements from the set of
>   values specified by `S`

Here, `S` can be an optional indexable collection, an array of values in your case (or a type like `Int`). So, above `S = [-0.5, 0.5]` and `rand` draws `N` random elements from this collection, which we can afterwards sum up.

**Assigning specific values to a boolean array**

Since this is the title of your question, and the answer above doesn't actually address this, let me comment on this as well.

You could do `sum((rand(N).<p)-0.5)`, i.e. you shift all the ones to `0.5` and all the zeros to `-0.5` to get the wanted result. Note that this is a general strategy: Let's say you want `true` to be `a` and `false` to be `b`, where `a` and `b` are numbers. You achieve this by `(rand(N).<p)*(a-b) + b`.

**However**, beyond being more "complicated", `sum((rand(N).<p)-0.5)` will allocate temporary arrays, first one of booleans, then one of numbers, the latter of which will eventually go into `sum`. Because of these unnecessary allocations this approach will be slower than the solution above.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the explanation. It was very clear and explained using terminology someone like me can understand. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad I could clarify things for you.